# How do I turn on iphone screen programmatically when it's dimmed

Tags: ios, screen

Before iphone lock the screen, it will dim the screen first for a while. I wonder how to lighten the screen in my app at that time without touching the screen. Can anyone give a help?

To be more specific: I don't want to prevent the system sleep, nor adjust the screen brightness. What I want is to lighten the screen when I got a certain event to notice the user while the screen is dimmed.

Just solve this problem in a tricky way..

```
- (void)lightenTheScreen
{    
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is default behavior of the iPhone. To prevent that nature you can use following code.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled: YES]; //Add this at the end in your applicationDidFinishLaunching application
```

From [APPLE DOCUMENTATION](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> "The default value of this property is NO. When most applications have
>   no touches as user input for a short period, the system puts the
>   device into a "sleep” state where the screen dims. This is done for
>   the purposes of conserving power. However, applications that don't
>   have user input except for the accelerometer—games, for instance—can,
>   by setting this property to YES, disable the “idle timer” to avert
>   system sleep. "

Comment: Hi Jennis, thanks for your answer. But I think you misunderstood my question. I don't want to prevent the system sleep. What I want is to lighten the screen when I got some event to notice the user while the screen is dimmed.